# How to undo "hg qnew"?

Tags: mercurial, undo, mercurial-queue, backout

I issued `hg qnew` without realizing that it includes any outstanding changes into the patch. I'd like to back that out and pick only specific changes using `hg qrecord`. How can I undo `qnew`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your answer definitely works — with newer Mercurial's you can use `hg strip --keep` to avoid doing the import step:

```
$ hg strip --keep .
$ hg qdelete patch-name
```

The `--keep` flag makes strip ignore the working copy while working, that is, it deletes the commit (like `hg qpop` would do) but it doesn't undo the changes to the files. After stripping you still have the patch in your series (unapplied) and you can then delete it.

Answer (score 2):

I've found an anwer [here](http://www.mentby.com/Group/mercurial/how-to-back-out-qnew.html):

```sh
hg qpop
hg import --no-commit .hg/patches/patch-name
hg qdelete patch-name
```

Please add a better way, if you know.

**Update:** Based on Aldo's answer, there is another way:

```sh
hg qnew test
# We can undo the above qnew as:
hg qrefresh -X '*'
hg qpop -f
hg qdelete test
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to undo the latest `qnew` retaining all your local changes, one option is:

```
qcrefresh 123
hg qpop -f
hg qdelete <name of the patch>
```

Notice that `123` is just a random string: you are telling mercurial to only include the (hopefully nonexistsnt) `123` file in the current patch.
Newer versions of Mercurial When you issue will issue a warning about the fact `123` file does not exist, but this is exactly what we want here.

If you want to retain some of the changes in the current path, you can use the `qcrefresh` command from the [crecord](https://bitbucket.org/edgimar/crecord/wiki/Home) [extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CrecordExtension), which allows to graphically select the changes to be included in the current patch. You need to [download](http://bitbucket.org/edgimar/crecord/get/tip.zip) it from Bitbucket, extract the archive and configure it in `.hgrc`:

```
[extensions]
crecord = <path/to/crecord/package>
```

Comment: This extension seems very promising, and as a darcs user I like this way of selecting changes interactively. However, it doesn't answer my question - I needed to undo `qnew` that has already happened.

Comment: If I understand well your question, you don't actually need to undo the `qnew`: you can directly use the `qcrefresh` command to exclude the changes that were not meant to be included. The excluded changes will remain as local changes, so after `qcrefresh` you can include them all in a new patch with `qnew` or even use `qcrecord` to only select a subset of them.

Comment: Perhaps I just don't understand how to use the extension properly. Could you please add a series of command starting with `hg qnew` on a modified repository, which ends as if `qnew` was never invoked? I tried to this using `qrefresh` before (which I suppose does the same thing as `qcrefresh`, only non-interactively), but without success.

Comment: I've just edited my answer. With the `qrefresh` `--include` and `--exclude` options you can select which files to include in the patch `qcrecord` lets you choose the single hunks.